# mysql time difference computation with a twist

Tags: mysql, math

From a mysql result, I get something like this

```
last_updated_rta    gmt_timestamp        last_record_update       diff
  02:14:58       2013-02-24 02:15:37    2013-02-23 19:15:37      00:00:39
  01:01:00       2013-02-24 01:30:34    2013-02-23 18:30:34      00:29:34
  23:59:59       2013-02-24 00:29:33    2013-02-23 17:29:33     -23:30:26
  00:00:00       2013-02-24 00:29:33    2013-02-23 17:29:33      00:29:33
```

The 'diff' column is a timediff computation:

```
         TIMEDIFF(TIME(gmt_timestamp),TIME(last_updated_rta)) AS diff
```

Here's the problem.  Note the '-23:30:26' value in the "diff" column.  I shouldn't have a negative.  This only happens if the last_updated_rta time is before midnight (00:00:00) and the gmt_timestamp date is the next day.  Part of the problem, I think, is that I don't get a date value for the "last_updated_rta" column.  I only have the time.

How can I correct this formula to account for this so I don't get negative values?

Thanks in advance,

- d -

Comment: It is possible that you are having such a problem because the last_updated_rta has no date. Is it possible for you to add a date?

Comment: I can't add the date because the file I get the info from doesn't tell me what date it really is. I can only assume it's from the same day or previous day if after midnight GMT.

Comment: How will you know if the difference should be +23 hrs or just -1 hrs?

Comment: Does this only happen when last_updated_rta is before midnight, or every time that it is larger than gmt_timestamp?

Comment: The difference can never be negative. the gmt_timestamp is really just the gmt time of the current_timestamp so it's always the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *know* that you won't get any negative values, then test to see if the result is negative and if it is, add 1 day to the value of diff.

Comment: Hmm... I had tried variations of doing it like that before but that didn't work but I've tried it again and it seems to work now as this:
"IF(TIMEDIFF(TIME(gmt_timestamp),TIME(last_updated_rta))<0,ADDTIME(TIMEDIFF(TIME(gmt_timestamp),TIME(last_updated_rta)),'24:00:00'),TIMEDIFF(TIME(gmt_timestamp),TIME(last_updated_rta)))
"   
-  Thanks! -

Answer (score 1):

Assuming last_updated_rta is always **earlier** than gmt_timestamp, you can assume the date of last_updated_rta is the same as gmt_timestamp. If last_updated_rta happen to be **later** (diff gives negative) then you know its date should be previous day

Comment: I thought that at first as well but that's not necessarily true.  I worked with various versions of the formula using that idea and I think it didn't work for a 6 hour period ...